# Apache+mod_rewrite adding query string to my URL when no trailing slash is used

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm working on making an Apache web server multilingual and I decided to use gettext with my php code.

My idea was to rewrite all URLs that are requested and contain the two-letter country code by simple creating a query string parameter using that country code, for example

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en -> https://domain.com/newpage?l=en
https://domain.com/newpage/en/about -> https://domain.com/newpage/about?l=en
```

This would then be parsed further by rewrite_mod and the final page would be served.

In general, this approach is working, although I noticed strange behavior which depends on whether I use a trailing slash or not.

When I type the following URL into the browser:

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en/
```

everything is fine and I get served the English version of the page.

However, when I leave the trailing slash out:

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en
```

The address changes to

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en/?l=en
```

The rule I use is as follows:

```
RewriteRule /newpage/(en|pl|fi)(/?)(.*) /newpage/$3?l=$1 [QSA,S=1]
```

These are the logs from rewrite_mod that show the difference between the two cases:

```
https://domain.com/en
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /newpage/en/
(3) applying pattern '/newpage/(en|pl|fi)(/?)(.*)' to uri '/newpage/en/'
(2) rewrite '/newpage/en/' -> '/newpage/?l=en'
(3) split uri=/newpage/?l=en -> uri=/newpage/, args=l=en&l=en
(2) prefixed with document_root to /var/www/newpage/index.php
(1) go-ahead with /var/www/newpage/index.php [OK]

https://domain.com/en/
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /newpage/en/
(3) applying pattern '/newpage/(en|pl|fi)(/?)(.*)' to uri '/newpage/en/'
(2) rewrite '/newpage/en/' -> '/newpage/?l=en'
(3) split uri=/newpage/?l=en -> uri=/newpage/, args=l=en
(2) prefixed with document_root to /var/www/newpage/index.php
(1) go-ahead with /var/www/newpage/index.php [OK]
```

The two are almost exactly the same except for the 'split' message, which in the first case shows the extra l=en parameter.

What is even more odd, is that if I disable mod_rewrite, the behavior doesn't stop, i.e. typing in

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en
```

changes the address to

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en/?l=en
```

and produces error 404. I get the same error when I go to

```
https://domain.com/newpage/en/
```

but the address in the browser doesn't change. The Apache logs don't say anything about that.

Where does the extra parameter come from, if it's not mod_rewrite? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an interaction between mod_dir's DirectorySlash and your rewrite.  In 2.4, mod_dir has become a bit more aggressive about what requests it will handle, the next 2.4 release (2.4.8 or later, for posterity) will avoid taking mod_dir actions on the result of rewrites -- maybe this is your problem?

For now, I'd suggest DirectorySlash OFF in the context of this stuff and handling trailing slash with mod_rewrite where it is easier to see/tweak the ordering

Comment: I suspected mod_dir but I was too cautious/lazy to switch it off because I would need to go through my code and make sure I use the trailing slash in it. I will test it and see if it helps, though.